# How to fix A non-numeric value encountered in wp-includes/functions.php on line 72

Tags: php

Recently updated to PHP 7.2 and I've encountered multiple errors especially when logging in to the wordpress dashboard

Deactivating themes and plugins to solve errors is simple enough but this error is appearing in the functions.php so I'm unsure how to proceed, or even if I'm missing something obvious

MySQL 4
PHP 7.2

(the line third from the bottom is line 72, another reason I'm unsure of the error)

Thanks!

```
function current_time( $type, $gmt = 0 ) {

switch ( $type ) {
    case 'mysql':
        return ( $gmt ) ? gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) : gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', ( time() + ( get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) ) );
    case 'timestamp':
        return ( $gmt ) ? time() : time() + ( get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    default:
        return ( $gmt ) ? gmdate( $type ) : gmdate( $type, time() + ( get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) );
} 
}
```

Comment: try a `<?php echo get_option('gmt_offset'); ?>`, should return an integer value

Comment: Please share a full backtrace of that error message, along with your debugging attempts. Also, it could be a good idea to update your MySQL server - I could not find a definite date, but the last version of MySQL 4 is way more than ten years old

Answer (score 4):

Setting a timezone resolved, thanks for the pointer in comments @vivoconunxino .  This updates the value of `gmt_offset` in `wp_options` table to a number.

**Using WordPress admin**

1. Login to WordPress admin
2. Settings -> General -> Timezone
3. Set a timezone
4. Save changes

**Using wp cli**

Check the value with:
`wp option get gmt_offset`

Set the value for Los Angeles with: 
`wp option set gmt_offset -7`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Login to WordPress admin
Settings -> General -> Timezone
Set a timezone
Save changes

Thanks a lot.